# How to open unity assets store on editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use unity hub on Ubuntu18.04
unity assets ,such as Standard Assets, couldn’t  be imported.

Window > Asset store, Firefox is opened. Unity editor doesn’t show Assets Store.
I bought assets in web browser and click “open in unity”,
But unity editor doesn’t open.

I think web browser can’t connect unity.
So I’d like to open unity assets in unity editor.

Comment: In general in newer Unity versions (2020) the Unity built-in `AssetStore Window` was removed and is now only available via the [web browser](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetStore.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try This Steps,

1. Go To Package Manager In Unity Editor.
2. Click On Drop-down List Which Is Located At Top Left Corner And Select My Assets

You Can Find Your Purchased Assets There.